# What logic would I use to loop over every episode of a TV show by season and episode?

Tags: logic

I'm pulling in episode data from the TVRage API -- sort of an IMDb-like service that will return episode data if you send in a request "Season 4, Episode 5, of Show #4681".

I want to start from Season 1, Episode 1, and loop over everything until the show ends, whenever it does. I'm just not sure of how to write that logic. I guess in pseudocode it would be...

```
$season = 1;
$episode = 1;

add_title_to_database($season,$episode);
    if (that worked) $episode++, and do it again;
    else $e=1, $season++, and do it again; // because we've hit the end of the season

if you get two errors in a row, then incrementing the season counter didn't work because there are none left, so exit
```

But I'm not sure how I'd write that in a C-like language, or if that's even the right logic to be using. I don't have access to the episode counts ahead of time to look at, the only way I know where the seasons and shows end is when the requests get no results.

So what should I do?

Comment: I guess you would request incrementally until your request fails. So just define what your fail condition is - does it count as a "fail" because the string/data returned is empty/null?

Answer (score 0):

That would work, but you might not be able to tell the difference between an error due to going past the last episode and an error due to some other reason.  I noticed that TVRage can return an episode list.  Why not make that call first so you know that your making valid requests?

**EDIT:**
If you're using an XML parser, your logic should look something like:

```
for (season : episodelist.getChildren()) {
  for (episode: season.getChildren()) {
  }
}
```

Just for the record, the way you would solve this without the episode list would be:

```
int season = 1;
while (true) {
  boolean success = add_title_to_database(season, 1);
  if (! success) break;
  int episode = 2;
  while (true) {
    success = add_title_to_database(season, episode);
    if (! success) break;
    episode++;
  }
  season++;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's a good catch, I did miss that. However, dealing with the episode list still requires the same or very similar logic. The episode list is structured as an object with many season properties, each season property containing many episode properties, each episode property containing many lines of data, one of which is the title I want. So I still have to say "Season 0 episode 1, then 2, then 3, until fail, then Season 1, episode 1, then 2, until fail... quit at two fails in a row", etc. And that's what I don't know how to write.